# KivyMD materialyoucolor for Android

Tags: python, android, kivymd, buildozer

So i am building an app using KivyMD 2.0 using Buildozer, here is the list of requierments in Buidlozer.spec :

```
requirements = python3,kivy,exceptiongroup,asyncgui,asynckivy,fuzzywuzzy,python-Levenshtein,materialyoucolor,PIL,pytesseract,packaging,plyer,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

The app builds fine but when i deploy the app crashes with the error (i tried the app with kivyMD 1.2 it worked fine)

```
ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/materialyoucolor/quantize/celebi.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
```

ChatGPT told me the following :

> This suggests that the celebi.so file is built for x86_64
> architecture, but your device is using the ARM64 architecture. You may
> need to make sure that the materialyoucolor package you are using is
> compatible with the ARM64 architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Kivymd 2.0 still in dev, it's not working correctly, better if you use kivymd 1.1.1, if you use kivymd 1.2 buildozer going to try to install the 2.0 version and crash because the permission of pip.

Answer (score 0):

Use KivyMD v1.2.0, v2 requires materialyoucolor, which has no built distribution for aarch64.

Comment: that's what i am doing now, but i would like to use kivymd 2.0